# Change in mac address

Tags: networking, mac-address

Is it possible that MAC address gets changed when a system is moved from one network to another? I know that IP addresses can change when switching from one network to other. But is it possible with MAC address too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MAC address of the device does not change, but the MAC address as seen by the other side of the connection can change. Since many devices go through a router, the MAC address is that of the router, not the original equipment.

Some routers can change their MAC addresses to be the same as one of the devices attached to them.

Comment: @dadnick: thanks! but i am not clear with the last statement. why will the routers change their MAC address to be same as that of device attached?

Comment: @vish I stayed in a hotel that had wired internet access. In order for all of the people in the room to use the internet, I bought a router. The first internet page the guest was given was an internet usage agreement. After agreeing, the internet was set to OK for the MAC address on the port. Setting the router to the same MAC address made the internet available to everyone in the room.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, mac is bound to the physical interface and does not change by changing the network. Are you maybe getting some other mac of a relay or something similar?

Comment: No, i was confused with the contradictory statements i read on a site regarding change of mac address when switching to other network.

Answer (score 0):

Unlikely in your circumstance.

Unless there lies some sneaky virus that flashes your devices' internal systems and replaces their mac addresses.  Wouldn't that be sneaky!

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the settings panel, network connections,properties then configure and finally advanced settings. Now you can change your NetworksAddress (MAC address).

Here is a tutorial in French : http://www.siteduzero.com/tutoriel-3-363683-et-maintenant-la-pratique.html